# A tenants stove quit

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting

My tenants stove just quit. I inspected it, and the ground wire was blackened. I checked the breaker, and it doesn't have the resistance it should when resetting. All other breakers do? Should I replace the stove...or the breaker on the panel?

Comment: Is working on your tennants electrical legal where you are?

Comment: clearly the breaker needs replacement and stove needs inspection since it caused the problem

Comment: So test the breaker, replace if needed. You are licensed etc to do this?

Comment: Is it a 3-prong terminal? That isn't ground!

Answer (score 1):

If the ground is blackened and the breaker is no longer working normally, then the chances are that the stove shorted out.  The current surge may have damaged the breaker.

Replace the breaker, then replace or repair the stove.

Comment: The wire that was "blackened" needs to be replaced, too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this has been working for a while and since you did not install this you just inspected it consider, seriously consider, getting a professional to come diagnose and repair the problem. Expect to also  replace the stove. There is a possibility the stove failed and may be under warranty, something you need to check out. While the pro is there have them validate the breaker and wire sizes used in the installation.

I base this on the fact that you have a failed breaker and melted wire in the stove something is badly wrong. I am not sure if you indicate resistance in the mechanical or electrical sense so I am assuming mechanical.